# How to use FFI:def-call-in in clisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, ffi, clisp

I have figured out how to make use of shared objects created from C code into Clisp using `FFI:def-call-out` but I am not able to figure out how to use `FFI:Def-call-in`.

I don't know the process and actually I am confused if clisp will also create some .so file that some C function can use or something else.

Can someone please explain a minimal working example for writing such callback functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Example 32.7. Calling Lisp from C](http://clisp.org/impnotes/dffi.html#ex-call-in):

To sort an array of double-floats using the Lisp function `SORT` instead of the C library function `qsort`, one can use the following interface code `sort1.c`. The main problem is to pass a variable-sized array.

```
extern void lispsort_begin (int);
void* lispsort_function;
void lispsort_double (int n, double * array) {
  double * sorted_array;
  int i;
  lispsort_begin(n); /* store #'sort2 in lispsort_function */
  sorted_array = ((double * (*) (double *)) lispsort_function) (array);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) array[i] = sorted_array[i];
  free(sorted_array);
}
```

This is accompanied by `sort2.lisp`:

```
(DEFPACKAGE "FFI-TEST" (:use “COMMON-LISP” “FFI”))
(IN-PACKAGE "FFI-TEST")
(EVAL-WHEN (compile) (setq FFI:*OUTPUT-C-FUNCTIONS* t))
(FFI:DEF-CALL-IN lispsort_begin (:ARGUMENTS (n int))
  (:RETURN-TYPE nil)
  (:LANGUAGE :stdc))
(FFI:DEF-C-VAR lispsort_function (:type c-pointer))
(defun lispsort_begin (n)
  (setf (cast lispsort_function
              `(c-function
                 (:ARGUMENTS (v (c-ptr (c-array double-float ,n))))
                 (:RETURN-TYPE (c-ptr (c-array double-float ,n))
                               :malloc-free)))
        #'sort2))
(defun sort2 (v)
  (declare (type vector v))
  (sort v #'<))
```

To test this, use the following test file `sorttest.lisp`:

```
(EVAL-WHEN (compile) (setq FFI:*OUTPUT-C-FUNCTIONS* t))
(FFI:DEF-CALL-OUT sort10
  (:name "lispsort_double")
  (:LANGUAGE :stdc)
  (:ARGUMENTS (n int)
              (array (c-ptr (c-array double-float 10)) :in-out)))
```

Now try

```
$ clisp-link create sort sort2.c sorttest.c
$ cc -O -c sort1.c
$ cd sort
$ ln -s ../sort1.o sort1.o
```

Add `sort1.o` to `NEW_LIBS` and `NEW_FILES` in `link.sh`. Create a file `package.lisp` containing the form

```
(MAKE-PACKAGE "FFI-TEST" :use '(“COMMON-LISP” “FFI”))
```

and add `package.lisp` to `TO_PRELOAD` in `link.sh`. Proceed:

```
$ cd ..
$ base/lisp.run -M base/lispinit.mem -c sort2.lisp sorttest.lisp
$ clisp-link add base base+sort sort
$ base+sort/lisp.run -M base+sort/lispinit.mem -i sort2 sorttest
> (sort10 10 '#(0.501d0 0.528d0 0.615d0 0.550d0 0.711d0
                0.523d0 0.585d0 0.670d0 0.271d0 0.063d0))
#(0.063d0 0.271d0 0.501d0 0.523d0 0.528d0 0.55d0 0.585d0 0.615d0 0.67d0 0.711d0)
$ rm -r base+sort
```

Comment: what is base/lisp.run and listinit.mem here...I found this example but here I am stuck.

Comment: these are clisp run-time and memory image files; `clisp --help` will print their location on the second line.